# Invertibility of matrix in Woodbury Matrix Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Woodbury Matrix Identity states that given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
 , $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$
 , $C\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$
  and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$
  such that $A,C$
  are nonsingular one has $$\left(A+UCV\right)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U\left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U\right)^{-1}VA$$

I have no problem proving this under assumption that $(A+UCV)$ is nonsingular but I'm wondering why the fact that $A,C$ are nonsingular implies this. I tried deriving this from the Matrix Determinant lemma without success.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly isn't true. E.g. when $n=k$ and $U=C=V=-A=I$, both $A$ and $C$ are invertible but $A+UCV=0$ is not.

Comment: That's a really good point, this explains why the whole thing seemed suspicious to begin with. Thanks!